Debugging iptables masquerade with a bridge
I have created a network namespace with one half of a veth pair, the other half being in the root namespace attached to a bridge. I have created an iptables masquerade rule like this:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 ! -o my-br -j MASQUERADE

where 10.0.0.0/24 is the subnet for my bridge. The output of ip route in the root namespace is:
default via 192.168.88.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.0.0/24 dev my-br proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 

from within the network namespace I can successfully ping the bridge at 10.0.0.1 as well as the host at 192.168.88.198. However, if I try to ping some host on the public internet then my pings receive no replies:
$ sudo ip netns exec my-ns ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
(hangs)

I have enabled IP forwarding.
It seems that my masquerade rule isn't working. I can see the outgoing icmp packets via tcpdump, and no return packets going the other way:
$ sudo tcpdump -i my-br icmp                            
listening on my-br, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
17:43:14.288051 IP 10.0.0.50 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 2477, seq 4, length 64
17:43:15.311982 IP 10.0.0.50 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 2477, seq 5, length 64
17:43:16.336076 IP 10.0.0.50 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 2477, seq 6, length 64

If I do the same on my host's main network interface, I see nothing. Would I expect to see something here if the masquerade were working? I was thinking that I would see the outgoing ICMP packets here if it was working.
$ sudo tcpdump -i wlo1 icmp
listening on wlo1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
(nothing here)

I have docker installed. Perhaps its NAT rules are somehow intefering with my setup? The subnet I'm using 10.0.0.x doesn't seem to conflict with what docker is using. My full iptables nat table is:
$ sudo iptables -t nat --list-rules
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 ! -o my-br -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN

I don't really know how to make sense of the above. Does the -N DOCKER line mean everything is being passed to the docker chain?

Is the masquerade rule matching (does the counter visible in iptables -vL ... increment for outgoing connections)? If you add a -J LOG rule just before the MASQUERADE rule, what do the log messages look like?

The -N DOCKER line just creates a new chain named DOCKER. The -J DOCKER lines direct matching traffic to that chain (but execution will continue in the parent chain if none of the rules in the DOCKER chain match).
